# Should the names of seasons be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, seasons

When you are writing about the seasons, should you capitalize their names?

For example, would you say:

> I love the colors of the leaves in Autumn.

Or should you say:

> I love the colors of the leaves in autumn.

Comment: For some reason, in elementary school I was taught that Autumn is capitalized, but not the others.  (I suspect this was a schoolteacher's misinterpretation of some P-ist principle.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The names of seasons should be left uncapitalized. However capitalization may be used to achieve a poetic effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should say:

> I love the colors of the leaves in autumn.

Answer (score -1):

Just like days of the week, seasons' names are kind of proper nouns; they have a temporal meaning; therefore, they should be capitalized.

Comment: THat may have some logic to it, but it is obviously not followed in English.

Comment: Hi Taoufik, Good answer but please add support to why you think your answer is correct. e.g Why is season name a proper noun. Adding links to dictionary meaning is always to good practice! :)

Answer (score -3):

Particular seasons are temporal elements, in exactly the same way as a day of the week or a month of the year. They pinpoint a specific region of time. As such, seasons should be capitalized. However, the actual word 'season' (like any generic time period), should not be capitalized, as a particular time period is not being specified.

**Examples:**

*In many areas, school now starts in the middle of Summer, technically. --
We're planning a trip for sometime next season.*

*The next tournament isn't until November. --
There is an event planned every month.*

*Your car will be ready on Wednesday. --
Your order should get to you in a few days.*

Comment: Any source for this assertion?