# When do you capitalize the names of seasons?

Tags: capitalization, seasons

Which sentence uses the correct capitalization for the name of the season?

> I will travel in the summer of 2013.

or

> I will travel in the Summer of 2013.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39448/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8321/2085

Comment: I keep seeing seasons capitalized in Robert Caro's "Path to Power" (biography of LBJ). Pg 133: "He had started work in Winter." but even more strangely: "Spring was more pleasant, but Spring was followed by Summer, the Hill Country summer where laborers toiled..." then again: "And Summer became Autumn and then Winter again; the first cut of the wind of this new Winter may have..." Originally published in 1982 by Knopf, though this printing's from 2013. Anybody know what's up with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In contemporary English, you now normally capitalize the names of the seasons only when they are personified.

For personification, think of “poetic” or “creative” uses, where the season is thought of as possessing the characteristics of a person, and so becomes  a proper noun meriting a capital letter.

- In March, Spring shows her joyous moods.
- All Nature hides from Winter’s icy breath.
- We will muse on Summer’s ploys:
  How no partial gifts are hers,
  But now the palms and now the first
  Are dozed with kisses balmy-sweet
  From lips which breathe a pulsing heat.
  — Charles Mair
- O WILD West Wind, thou breath of Autumn's being    
  Thou from whose unseen presence the leaves dead    
  Are driven like ghosts from an enchanter fleeing,
  — Percy Bysshe Shelley
- If Winter comes, can Spring be far behind?
  — Percy Bysshe Shelley
- Where are the songs of Spring? Ay, where are they?  
      Think not of them, thou hast thy music too,—  
  While barred clouds bloom the soft-dying day, 
      And touch the stubble plains with rosy hue; 
  — John Keats

Also, Midwinter and Midsummer are often capitalized, as they are specific days.

Finally, the named seasons of **a named year** are also capitalized:

- Back during Spring ’09, we had snow all the way till May.
- We aren’t running the class for the Fall Semester.

Comment: What are your sources for this answer?

Comment: @NathanArthur [Every single style guide out there](https://www.google.com/?client=safari#q=capitalize+seasons). It’s common knowledge. I have never seen anything that contradicts this.

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen anyone *contradict* it. I've just had trouble finding where   a reputable authority states that it's accepted practice to capitalize a season simply because it's combined with a date. It makes sense to me, I think it looks right, and I haven't heard anyone say it's wrong. Just have had trouble finding a source so was wondering if you had one. (And, yes, I did that Google search.)

Comment: Oh, I see; I'm sorry. I hadn't realized you meant the very last part about the particular year. Now that you mention it, I don't know where I got that from!

Comment: Oh, yeah, guess I should have been more specific. :) No worries. If it happens to come to you, I would be interested to hear.

Comment: @NathanArthur, tchrist: Based on your experiences, would you mind looking over these and letting me know which ones should be capitalized?
(1) *"I always take classes in the fall semester."*,
(2) *"I took classes in the fall semester of 2015."*,
(3) *"I took classes in fall 2015."*,
(4) *"I will be taking classes in the fall semester."*,
(5) *"I will take classes in the fall."*

Comment: @Mehrdad According to tchrist, I think 2 & 3 would be capitalized; but I never found any good sources.

Comment: @NathanArthur: Yeah, the reason I asked is that I see other sources (like [this](https://www.regent.edu/admin/mktsrv/editorial_style/p-s.cfm)) saying that *specific* instances of seasons should be capitalized, but which would imply capitalizing 2-5... yet personally I feel like it's most natural to capitalize all of them. Side note, but if you capitalize fall, do you also capitalize semester? It looks quite jarring to me but it seems the consensus is yes?

Comment: I took class in the Fall Semester 2015 [as listed in a catalog of courses). That is the only time it would be capitalized. In reference to an official listing, to be just like it.//I don't think that personified seasons in contemporary poetry are necessarily capitalized at all.

Comment: I don't see a reputable source in this answer that supports "Exports were increasing in Fall 1990" over "Exports were increasing in fall 1990" The closest I can find is a mention that seasons of named years [should be capitalized when referring to periodical issue dates](https://erinwrightwriting.com/capitalize-seasons-solstices-equinoxes/) and references various style guides to support it.

Comment: https://www.amherst.edu/news/communications/editorial-services-media/styleguide/node/84702 says don't capitalize unless it's the name of an academic season

Comment: I don't think that *Fall Semester* is a name of a season at all; it is the name of a semester. It stands for whatever the regulations of the relevant institution specify, which may only roughly correspond to the season it is named after.